# Lost all my custom keyboard shortcuts

Tags: shortcut

So I think I accidentally deleted my shortcut presets by a mis click and can't get them back.

I believe I had a custom preset name and I accidentally clicked '-', which immediately deleted my custom presets and set them back to default.

All the keyboard shortcuts I carefully set over the months / years are gone.

I thought I had been saving the shortcuts when I clicked "Save User Settings" in the user preferences file. Unfortunately this does not appear to be the case. I backed up both that file and the startup.blend file. Unfortunately loading startup does not have the shortcuts either.

Am I fated to go through and redefine all the shortcuts again? I suppose everything is a learning experience..

[image: list]

Comment: Did you try saving with **Ctrl-U**?

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth -- I have been using th Ctrl-U option lately, Blender 2.9, and it does not save the shortcuts (e.g. Mesh, Edges, rotate CW -> shortcut: Ctrl+A). I have to add shortcut every startup.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you just upgraded Blender, and didn't click 'Copy Previous Settings' in the splash screen. This would copy your settings of 2.78 to 2.79; without this, Blender uses the defaults after an upgrade.

If you haven't saved new settings yet, the 'Copy Previous Settings' button will still be available in the splash screen. If you want to remove your 2.79 settings, you have to visit a platform-dependent path. These paths are documented in [the Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/getting_started/installing/configuration/directories.html).

Comment: Care to complete this answer by explaining how to do it? (On a Mac the files to modify are in ~/Library/Application Support/Blender/ then there's a version folder... forgot what it is on Windows, and I've never tried it on Linux.)

Comment: I've expanded my answer a bit. The "Copy Previous Settings" button can always be clicked as long as you haven't saved new settings yet. Those paths are in the Blender manual, and have been pasted in many Stack Exchange answers already so I won't paste them here again.

Comment: Thanks for the info, though I did not upgrade Blender. This is something that definitely happened after a mis-click on the keyboard shortcuts screen. I guess I'm asking, is the current (or rather, previous) keyboard shortcut file saved anywhere internally?

Update: I was able to recover most of the shortcuts from a keyboard-shortcut.py file I exported and copied to another machine. So I'm good to go. In the future I will manually export the keyboard shortcut files using the "Export Key Configuration" button at the bottom.

Comment: You can always sync your settings to [Blender Cloud](https://cloud.blender.org/services), even without paying for a subscription that feature is available.

Comment: I have the latest, 2.9 version, and this is still a mystery. On Quit, the shortcuts vanish.